# How to create a new variable on condition of others in R

Tags: r, if-statement, variables, conditional-statements

I have the following data frame:

```
ID   Measurement A      Measurement  B     Date of Measurements A and B   Date of Measurement C
1    23                 24                 12                             16
1    22                 23                 12                             15
1    24                 22                 12                             17
1    21                 20                 12                             11
1    27                 29                 12                             17
```

This is example using 1 Identifier (ID), in reality I have thousands.

I want to create a variable which encapsulates

> ***"if this ID's Measurement A OR Measurement B is > xxx, before the date of Measurement C, ON MORE THAN TWO OCCASSIONS, then designate
> them a 1 in a new column called new_var".***

So far, I removed all Date of Measurements A and B > Date of Measurement C

```
measurements <- subset(measurements, dateofmeasurementsAandB < dateofmeasurementC)
```

And then added in the cut offs in an ifelse statement

```
measurements$new_var<- ifelse(measurements$measurementA >= xxx | measurements$measurementB >= xxx, 1, 0)
```

But can't factor in the 'on more than one occasion bit' (as you can see from example, each ID has multiple rows/occasions)

Any help would be great, especially if it could be done simpler!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I undestand what you're asking, I think I would use dplyr's count function:

```
#Starting from your dataframe
library(tidyverse)
df <- measurements %>%
         filter(dateofmeasurementsAandB < dateofmeasurementC,
                measurements$measurementA >= xxx | measurements$measurementB >= xxx)
```

This data frame should only have the conditions you're going for, so now we count them and filter the result:

```
df <- df %>% count(ID) %>% filter(n >= 2)
```

The vector **df$ID** should now only have the IDs that have been measured more than once which you can then feed back into your **measurements** data frame with ease, but I'm partial to this:

```
measurements$new_var <- 0
measurements[measurements$ID %in% df$ID]$new_var <- 1
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much for this! But how do I include the condition 'if measurements$measurementA >= xxx | measurements$measurementB >= xxx on more than one occasion' in this? Because each ID has multiple measurements so I need to find the rows that have measurements$measurementA >= xxx | measurements$measurementB >= xxx on more than one occassion, per ID. Sorry for not being clear!

Comment: So, the first thing I did was filter to make sure that all the things you want are true (i.e. A and B are both greater than some number and the dates of AB are before C).  The count statement then goes in and counts every time this happens grouped by ID.  If that count is greater than 1, then it must have happened multiple times.